# How to check current language of awful.widget.keyboardlayout?

Tags: awesome-wm

On my awesomewm panel, I have added the keyboard layout object:

```
mykeyboardlayout = awful.widget.keyboardlayout()
```

It changes between two languages when I press Caps Lock:

```
localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap gb,ara pc105 ,qwerty_digits grp:caps_toggle
```

How can I check in awesome which language is currently set ('**ar**' or '**gb**') so that I can display a symbol instead of just text?

Comment: You could write your own widget. The code seems to use `awesome.xkb_get_group_names()` and connects to the `xkb::map_changed` and `xkb::group_changed` signals: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/1932bd017f1fd433a74f621d9fe836e355ec054a/lib/awful/widget/keyboardlayout.lua#L241 Oh and `awesome.xkb_get_layout_group()`

Comment: Thank you Uli. But I don't think I currently have enough experience to write this widget. It's okay, I can live without it.